# I think my iphone 5's battery have some problem.

Tags: iphone, iso

One day i charged my iphone till 90%to92% then in didn't use my phone and went to sleep after 10 hours I checked my phone and the battery is showing only 20% charge is left. In the meantime i didn't used my phone so is there a battery issue or some thing else???

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a battery replacement program for iPhone 5. You can check eligibility on this [Apple page](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-battery/other_countries.html)

> Apple has determined that a very small percentage of iPhone 5 devices may suddenly experience shorter battery life or need to be charged more frequently. The affected iPhone 5 devices were sold between September 2012 and January 2013 and fall within a limited serial number range. (...)
>
> The program covers affected iPhone 5 batteries for two years after the first retail sale of the unit or until March 1, 2015, whichever provides longer coverage.

Comment: Definitely, the iPhone 5 is notorious for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see what application is consuming battery power. To check this, open Settings>General>Usage. Under Battery, touch 'Battery Usage'. After some loading time, you will see a list of Applications that have used Battery power in the last 24 hrs and last 7 days. If there is an application using a significant percentage of power that you have not used, you may wish to kill that app or restart your iPhone.

Specifically to the iPhone 5, see @Tetsujin response on extended warranty from Apple.